# Getting a blank screen with blinking cursor error after changing resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a dual boot. I allocated 30 gb space for root.when  I first plugged installation media, resolution wasn't optimum (it wasn't 1920x1080). I thought it would be okay after installation (as graphics card drivers are updated.. similar to windows) but that didn't happen. I watched several YouTube tutorials, visited websites and all i got was using "xrandr".(xrandr, addmode etc..)

One of the website said that "change to ubuntu xorg because it may happen in ubuntu(I can't remember name)bugs"...after that when i ran xrandr command i saw that monitor alias was changed to VGA-1 and all the commands run successfully but...
Screen resolution didn't change 
I saw that there's an option of 1920x1080(now visible) under display settings and i instantly applied it but but but....my pc showed a black screen with blinking cursor error i googled about it and they told me to upgrade apt-get blah blah...and also to update nvidia graphics card via command line..the process took time and i powere off the pc out of frustration. Can you suggest some methods to try? I just want to change screen resolution permanently